# SonarQube - TFS 2018 - Prepare analysis task failing with error (401) Unauthorized

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to use SonarQube (server version 7.3) with TFS 2018, however, the first task (SonarQube - Prepare analysis) is always failing with a 401 error. I am using the connector available at the Marketplace and also I followed all the available instructions.

If I call same SonarQube URL direct from outside TFS the using the same Token as configured I can get the JSON file that the SonarQube server returns, so I am thinking that this task is maybe using a wrong auth schema.

I made a test adding the parameters sonar.login and sonar.password in the Advanced -> Additional Properties, and this way it worked. However, the error was moved to the "Publish Quality Gate Result" task. It seems that is something with the TFS SonarQube service that is in the Marketplace.

Does anybody knows how to fix that? Thanks!

### Environment

- Server

  - TFS on-premises: TFS 2018 (Version 16.131.27701.1)
- Agent - Private:

  - Agent.OS | Windows_NT
  - Agent.OSVersion | 10.0.14393
  - Agent.Version | 2.120.2

#### Error logs

> 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z ##[section]Starting: SonarQube - Prepare
> analysis 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z Task         : Prepare Analysis
> Configuration 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z Description  : Prepare
> SonarQube analysis configuration 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z Version
> : 4.3.2 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z Author       : sonarsource
> 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z Help         : [More
> Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
> 2018-08-16T21:10:40.5523637Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-08-16T21:10:41.1773864Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
> 2018-08-16T21:10:41.2398894Z
> [command]C:\Builds_work_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.3.2\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe
> begin /k:$MYKEY 2018-08-16T21:10:41.2867651Z SonarScanner for MSBuild
> 4.3.1 2018-08-16T21:10:41.2867651Z Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild 2018-08-16T21:10:41.3336432Z Default
> properties file was found at
> C:\Builds_work_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.3.2\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
> 2018-08-16T21:10:41.3336432Z Loading analysis properties from
> C:\Builds_work_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.3.2\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
> 2018-08-16T21:10:41.3336432Z Pre-processing started.
> 2018-08-16T21:10:41.3336432Z Preparing working directories...
> 2018-08-16T21:10:41.3805197Z 15:10:41.38  Updating build integration
> targets... 2018-08-16T21:10:41.3961459Z 15:10:41.396  Fetching
> analysis configuration settings... 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4273969Z
>
> ### [error]15:10:41.427  Failed to request and parse '$SERVER_URL_HIDDEN/api/settings/values?component=$MYKEY': The remote
>
> server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
> 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4273969Z 15:10:41.427  Failed to request and parse
> '$SERVER_URL_HIDDEN/api/settings/values?component=$MYKEY': The remote
> server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
> 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4273969Z ##[error]15:10:41.427  Could not
> authorize while connecting to the SonarQube server. Check your
> credentials and try again. 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4273969Z 15:10:41.427
> Could not authorize while connecting to the SonarQube server. Check
> your credentials and try again. 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4273969Z
>
> ### [error]15:10:41.427  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4273969Z 15:10:41.427  Pre-processing failed. Exit
>
> code: 1 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4430235Z
>
> ### [error]C:\Builds_work_tasks\SonarQubePrepare_15b84ca1-b62f-4a2a-a403-89b77a063157\4.3.2\classic-sonar-scanner-msbuild\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe
>
> failed with return code: 1 2018-08-16T21:10:41.4430235Z
>
> ### [section]Finishing: SonarQube - Prepare analysis
>
> 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z ##[section]Starting: SonarQube - Publish
> Quality Gate Result 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z Task         : Publish Quality Gate
> Result 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z Description  : Publish SonarQube's
> Quality Gate result on the VSTS/TFS build result, to be used after the
> actual analysis. 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z Version      : 4.3.0
> 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z Author       : sonarsource
> 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z Help         : [More
> Information](http://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-tfs-ts.html)
> 2018-08-16T21:58:39.3075540Z
> ============================================================================== 2018-08-16T21:58:40.0888268Z ##[error][SQ] Could not fetch metrics
> 2018-08-16T21:58:40.0888268Z ##[error][SQ] API GET
> '/api/metrics/search' failed, status code was: 401
> 2018-08-16T21:58:43.0732984Z ##[error][SQ] API GET '/api/ce/task'
> failed, status code was: 401 2018-08-16T21:58:43.0732984Z
>
> ### [error][SQ] Could not fetch task for ID 'AWVEv14UfRI' 2018-08-16T21:58:43.0889233Z ##[section]Finishing: SonarQube - Publish
>
> Quality Gate Result